# Multi-shell parallel processing

Tags: bash, shell, subprocess

I wrote the script below to process 11 shell all simultaneously. (All at the same time)

```
#!/bin/sh
clear

for foo in ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM
do
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_Abandon_Brow.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_Abandon_Cart.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_ATC_Products.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_CheckoutProducts.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_InternalSearch.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_Natural_Search.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_PaidSearch.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_Products.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_PSID.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_SID.sh $foo &
   ssh XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.COM /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/bteq_Traits.sh

done;exit
```

The above script does process all 11 shells at the same time but then keeps looping running them over and over.

I am a little confused at why it is doing that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: not clear how that can work, but assuming you're having to mask your actual `ssh` remote hosts in the posting. Add a `set -vx` before the for loop and you'll see how the shell is expanding your `for for ..` line. It doesn't makes sense as is. For instance, I would expect the first loop to expand the `foo` var with the value `ssh`. Right? Good luck.

Comment: It's hard to tell whether this is intended to run on different servers from your obfuscating the hostnames. In any case, if you really need to anonymize the hostnames consider something shorter such as "example.com". It will make your question easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list with your servers and iterate using a `do` bucle, line by line, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read server <&3 
do
    ssh $server foo bar spam eggs # here be dragons... I mean, code
done 3< file.txt
exit 0
```

Comment: Without an `&` after the ssh line, how is this simultaneous?

Comment: ...also, what is the word "bucle" supposed to be?

Comment: _bucle_ is spanish for _loop_...  sorry, I got lost in translation :-)